# Remove matching values from custom ArrayList using another String ArrayList using single loop which use to add values to sqlite

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a custom ArrayList and String ArrayList in my Android application. I am using one for-loop for adding custom list values to sqlite. I also remove rows in the custom  ArrayList which will match with the value of the String ArrayList before adding to sqlite. I have to use two for-loops for this matter. Can I achieve this inside the sqlite adding loop?

```
 ArrayList<String> localRefNoList = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<SynchronizDTO> arr_sync = new ArrayList<>();
 
 public class SynchronizDTO {

    private String userName;
    private String referenceNo;
    private String employeeNo;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getReferenceNo() {
        return referenceNo;
    }
    public void setReferenceNo(String referenceNo) {
        this.referenceNo = referenceNo;
    }
    public String getEmployeeNo() {
        return employeeNo;
    }
    public void setEmployeeNo(String employeeNo) {
        this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
    }

}


for (int i = 0; i < arr_sync.size(); i++) {
    for (String ss : localRefNoList) {
        if (ss.equals(arr_sync.get(i).getReferenceNo().trim())) {
            arr_sync.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
                

for (int i = 0; i < arr_sync.size(); i++) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.userName, arr_sync.get(i).getUserName().trim());
    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.referenceNo, arr_sync.get(i).getReferenceNo().trim());
    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.employeeNo, arr_sync.get(i).getEmployeeNo().trim());

    try {
        restoreLogRes = db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.tbl_sms, null, cv);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a flag variable to do this in one go. And it will be much more intuitional if you do it on the removing loop rather than sqlite adding loop. Here I am optimizing a little bit. Also remember don't call for (int i = 0; i < arr_sync.size(); i++) here. It will calculate list size again and again. Rather do this :

```
int length = arr_sync.size();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    boolean flag = true;

    for (String ss : localRefNoList) {
        if (ss.equals(arr_sync.get(i).getReferenceNo().trim())) {
            arr_sync.remove(i);
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag){

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.userName, arr_sync.get(i).getUserName().trim());
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.referenceNo, 
        arr_sync.get(i).getReferenceNo().trim());
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.employeeNo, arr_sync.get(i).getEmployeeNo().trim());

        try {
            restoreLogRes = db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.tbl_sms, null, cv);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

}
```